# Can't create two-dimentional array in VBscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm trying to create two-dimentional array in VBscript, but I don't know the size of the array beforehands, so I put variables, but this code doesn't compile:

```
Dim countA: countA = 1
Dim countB: countB = 1
Dim countArray(countA, countB)
```

Classic ASp page with that code doesn't compile, while

```
Dim countArray(1, 1)
```

works perfectly fine.

Can I still implement a two-dimentional array using variables for the size of it?

Comment: "That is not working" doesn't mean anything.  Can you advise what error you are getting if any?  If you're not getting an error message, can you advise what is actually wrong, as in what is not as you expected?

Comment: I get HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error, Error Code 0x00000000 when requesting the page containing that code.

Comment: what error do you get at compile time ? what errors do you see on your IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured this out:

```
ReDim countArray(0, 0)
ReDim Preserve countArray(countA, countB)
```

Comment: Actually, you could have just used `Redim countArray(countA, countB)` without needing the `Preserve` or the initial setting to `(0,0)`